# Failed to load ibcrypto.so.3 using the Locally compiled OpenSSL

Tags: c, openssl, mpi, linker-errors, dynamic-linking

I have the following `Makefile`:

```
CC=mpicc

# use headers from builds/openssl
CFLAGS := -g -I${CURDIR}builds/openssl/include/openssl

# look for library in builds/openssl
LDFLAGS := -L${CURDIR}builds/openssl/lib
LIBS    := -lcrypto -lssl

.PHONY: all
all: builds/main

builds:
    mkdir -p $@

builds/main: builds/dh.o builds/message.o
builds/main: main.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $< builds/dh.o builds/message.o $(LDFLAGS) $(LIBS)

builds/dh.o: dh.h
builds/dh.o: dh.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ -c $<

builds/message.o: message.h
builds/message.o: message.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ -c $<

builds/dh.o builds/message.o builds/main: builds

# if you want to build openssl with your makefile...
builds/dh.o builds/message.o builds/main: builds/openssl
builds/openssl: builds
    cd openssl && ./config --prefix=${CURDIR}/builds/openssl --openssldir=${CURDIR}/builds/openssl && make && make test && make install

.PHONY: run

run: builds/main
    mpirun -quiet -np 3 xterm -hold -e ./builds/main &

.PHONY: debug

debug: builds/main
    mpirun -quiet -np 3 xterm -e gdb ./builds/main

.PHONY: clean

clean:
    rm -rf ./builds
```

That sompiles sucessfully my code. But whenb I try to ruin it via these commands:

```
make clean && make run
```

The application runs but I get the following error:

> ./builds/main: error while loading shared libraries: libcrypto.so.3: cannot open shared object file" No such file or directory

I tried to change my `Makefile` like that:

```
CC=mpicc

# use headers from builds/openssl
CFLAGS := -g -I${CURDIR}builds/openssl/include/openssl

# look for library in builds/openssl
LDFLAGS := -L${CURDIR}builds/openssl/lib
LIBS    := -lcrypto -lssl

.PHONY: all
all: builds/main

builds:
    mkdir -p $@

builds/main: builds/dh.o builds/message.o
builds/main: main.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $< builds/dh.o builds/message.o $(LDFLAGS) $(LIBS)

builds/dh.o: dh.h
builds/dh.o: dh.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ -c $<

builds/message.o: message.h
builds/message.o: message.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ -c $<

builds/dh.o builds/message.o builds/main: builds

# if you want to build openssl with your makefile...
builds/dh.o builds/message.o builds/main: builds/openssl
builds/openssl: builds
    cd openssl && ./config --prefix=${CURDIR}/builds/openssl --openssldir=${CURDIR}/builds/openssl && make && make test && make install

.PHONY: run

run: builds/main
    mpirun -quiet -np 3 xterm -hold -e ./builds/main &

.PHONY: debug

debug: builds/main
    mpirun -quiet -np 3 xterm -e gdb ./builds/main

.PHONY: clean

clean:
    rm -rf ./builds
```

And failed to compile at all:

```
main.c: In function ‘main’:
main.c:76:10: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘DH_get0_pub_key’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
   pubKey=DH_get0_pub_key(secret);
          ^
main.c:76:9: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
   pubKey=DH_get0_pub_key(secret);
         ^
main.c:125:5: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘DH_get0_p’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
   p=DH_get0_p(secret);
     ^
main.c:125:4: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
   p=DH_get0_p(secret);
    ^
/tmp/ccgccndI.o: In function `main':
/home/pcmagas/Kwdikas/master_thesis/mpi_dh/main.c:76: undefined reference to `DH_get0_pub_key'
/home/pcmagas/Kwdikas/master_thesis/mpi_dh/main.c:125: undefined reference to `DH_get0_p'
builds/dh.o: In function `generateKeys':
/home/pcmagas/Kwdikas/master_thesis/mpi_dh/dh.c:20: undefined reference to `DH_set0_pqg'
builds/dh.o: In function `generateKeyFromPreviousParticipant':
/home/pcmagas/Kwdikas/master_thesis/mpi_dh/dh.c:136: undefined reference to `DH_get0_priv_key'
/home/pcmagas/Kwdikas/master_thesis/mpi_dh/dh.c:147: undefined reference to `DH_get0_p'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:18: recipe for target 'builds/main' failed
```

Meaning if compared to the original result is fails to see the library at all whilst on the first error my project is compliled sucessfully but fails to load the dynamic library.

The OpenSSL is loaded via a git submodule as been in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54543348/4706711) in order to avoid using a possibly outdated version of it.

So how I can tell in the first case to load the dynamic library or even how I can build the OpenSSL as a static library/(ries)?

Answer (score 0):

It does not appear that you have added a runtime search path for dynamic libraries to your executable. Have a look at the `-rpath` link flag. Most likely, you will need to add something like `-Wl,-rpath,${CURDIR}/builds/openssl/lib` to your link flags.

Comment: fwiw, an other option is to `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=${CURDIR}builds/openssl/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH`

Comment: Not really an option because then you need that set in your environment every time you want to run the binary.

Comment: Strictly speaking, that is still an option - that does not require a rebuild if there is a typo in the command ;-) And yet an other option is to build openssl as a static library only.